# Google search by image "image_content" format?

Tags: http, format, compression

I'm trying to create an Application, which is able to upload an image to https://www.google.de/searchbyimage/upload. I got that working (Posting multipart/form-data via C#)

The only thing I now need to know is:
How is the image sent by the browser usually? In the multipart/form-data I found something called "image_content" in a sniffed request, what stores the image data.
But I don't know which format the image is stored.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryumAjUbPr6ymfh8hM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_content"

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
------WebKitFormBoundaryumAjUbPr6ymfh8hM
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the snippet of code you're using to post the multipart/form-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default encoding is base64. You should form a request that matches your sniffed request, except for the following:

- The `WebKitFormBoundaryumAj...` string should have a random string appended to ensure its uniqueness
- The `_9j_` line should be replaced with the base64-encoded contents of the image you are uploading.

The server will automatically detect the type of file (JPG, PNG, etc) so you shouldn't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded image. You can actually use it in many places, such as in CSS and in JavaScript. You can basically place it anywhere, where usual URI would be required. You can also encode many different things in such way (typefaces used in @font-face, for example).

In most modern computer languages there is built in functionality for base64 encoding – just google for one in C# if that's what you're using.

You can read more on the usage of data-URIs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs and perhaps here: http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/